# How to correctly format df pipe through genmon?

Tags: grep, pipe, panel, xfce, linux-disk-free

I am having trouble with command output formatting.

In terminal this works nicely:

```
df | grep sda1 | head -c33 | tail -c7 | tr -d " "
```

In genmon, I get only numbers such as "1145944":

```
SDAFREE=$(df | grep sda1 | head -c33 | tail -c7 | tr -d " ")
echo="$SDAFREE"
```

How do I print that command's output through genmon to xfce panel correctly (same as in terminal)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with every command with a pipe. As a workaround I put the command in a executable script and run the script in genmon.

BTW:
if you want just one value of a table, you can use awk instead of head, tail and tr:

```
df | awk '/sda1/ {print $4}'
```